# Why is Google Analytics telling me my regex is invalid?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-analytics

I am trying to match the below url pattern using the ****Matching RegExp**** advanced filter on the Landing Page dimension:

`/shop/lenses/sigma--f-1-4--35-mm--prime-fixed-focal-length.html`

with this regex:

`^\/shop\/lenses\/[a-z]+\-\-f\-([\d\-]+?)\-\m+\-\-prime\-fixed\-focal\-length\.html$`

This type of page has three attribute variables that come after /lenses and before /prime-fixed-focal-length.html sometimes there is only hyphen and one digit after f and other times there can be two sets of hyphenated digits.

**3 Attribute Patterns**

**First Variable Value** --
First word after `/lenses/` subdirectory and before `--f`

**Second Variable Value** --
Digit values that come after `--f-` (potentially can be 2 digits that will always have a hyphen between them)

**Third Variable Value** --
Digit values that come before `-mm--` (potentially can be 1-3 digits that will never have a hyphen separating the digits)

Regexr.com is telling me it should work, but Google Analytics tells me it's invalid
(see attached image for Google Analytics prompt when applying the matching regexp filter)

[Google Analytics Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZfoj.png)

Comment: There's no image attached.

Comment: If the regexp is in a string, you need to escape the backslashes. There's also no need to escape forward slash.

Comment: How do you escape the backslashes? I thought backslashes were the escape character?

Comment: does the filter require you to a match a full url or just the path? because this will only match the ending path, like you provided. if it matching against a full url you will need to remove the `^` at the begining.

Comment: Yes, it is. That's why you need to escape it, so it will be seen literally when the string is converted to a regexp. Escape it by putting another backslash before it.

Comment: so like this ```/shop/lenses/[a-z]+\\-\\-f\\-([\\d\\-]+?)\\-\\m+\\-\\-prime\\-fixed\\-focal\\-length\\.html$```

Answer (score 0):

Thier engine for whatever reason doesn't seem to know that `\d` is a digit.
By replacing it to `[0-9]` class seems to fix it up.

Analytics Cheat Sheet ?
https://www.analyticsmarket.com/blog/regular-expressions-for-google-analytics/

Google Analytics RegEx tester:
https://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/regex-tester/

Regex: `^/shop/lenses/[a-z]+--f-[0-9-]+?-m+--prime-fixed-focal-length\.html$`

Target: `/shop/lenses/sigma--f-1-4--35-mm--prime-fixed-focal-length.html`